# How to make slide effect for a single div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have main div which has many div like grid inside it. actually now horizontal scroll working but i want to make slide effect like [this][2]

[image]

sliding has to be done according to screen size not depending on the div.

I tried like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- META -->
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" /> 

        <style type="text/css">
            .fluidHeight {
                position: relative;
                width: 800px;
                height: 800px;
            }

            /* 
             * below 900px, switch to percentage based responsive height.
             * padding of 33.333% is calculated by using the 
             * image ratio 300px/900px = .333 * 100% = 33.333% 
             */
            @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

                .fluidHeight {
                    height: 0;
                    padding: 0 0 33.333% 0;
                }

            }

            .sliderContainer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 800px;
                height: 800px;
            }

            .iosSlider {
                width: 800px;
                height: 800px;
                background: #aaa;
            }

            .iosSlider .slider {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .iosSlider .slider img {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 800px;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
            }
            .div-body_2_col {
                -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-count:2;
                padding:5px;    
                height: 800px;
                }
        </style>

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "../../../_lib/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "../../../_lib/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>

        <!-- iosSlider plugin -->
        <script src = "../../../_src/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
                    snapToChildren: true,
                    desktopClickDrag: true,
                    infiniteSlider: true
                });

            });
        </script>

        <title>Ex #12: Image Slides</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = 'fluidHeight'>

            <div class = 'sliderContainer'>

                <div class = 'iosSlider'>

                    <div class = 'slider'>
                        <div class="div-body_2_col">
                        <div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

111.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>
<div class="newspaper" id="newspaper2" onClick="fn('newspaper2');">

2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div><div class="newspaper"  id="newspaper1" onClick="fn('newspaper1');">

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit 
</div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Can any one help me

Thank's in advance

Comment: Please, share your code here..

Comment: you shouldn't have multiple elements with same id's. Check [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class).

Comment: post only html and jquery that matters, not all the document. Then clearify html concept of class and id's

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all divs to the left you can just put them in an outer box and move the whole box to the left.
If you want to move only one div you could use css translation because this doesn't influence your layout (it just overlays/underlays the other divs). If you've floating divs and want to move only one specific div it could be tricky to avoid the others from moving also (working with negative margin on the left and positive on the right might work here).